# Asp.net: Saving data from JQuery Dialog modal into database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I'm new in using JQuery and Asp.net. I work on a small project using JQuery with Asp.net.I wrote small code which contain When a button when i clicked it dialog modal appears and contains form data. I want to save this form data from JQuery dialog into database. Please i need your help.

Comment: I'd use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in your JavaScript to send an HTTP message with the data.  On your server I would use `ASP.NET Web Api` (you can find it with NuGet Package Manager if your project doesn't have it already).  Create an `ApiController` to handle the request and save to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code from one I;ve done in the passed.

```
 $('[id$=LnkAdd]').click(function () {
            $(".update").dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: "Add New Events",
                width: '400',
                open: function (type, data) {
                    $(this).parent().appendTo("form")
                }
            });

      <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkAdd" OnClientClick="return false" runat="server" Text="Add Event Type"></asp:LinkButton>
        <div class="update" style="display: none">               


       <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd" placeholder="Add new event" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Event" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />         

        </div>
```

And then just pass the values from the textbox to your insert statement

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please can you write the code of btnAdd_Click function.